# Microsoft Dynamics GP 10 uninstall artifacts

Tags: c#, .net, vba, dynamics-gp

When Microsoft Dynamics GP 10 is uninstalled, what artifacts does it leave behind?

I'm asking because I'm experiencing strange focus-related behaviors in GP 2010 on computers that previously had GP 10 installed but the strange behaviors don't occur on machines that have never had GP 10 installed. More specifically, the strange behavior occurs when VBA tied to a local field (push button) displays a form from a custom DLL that’s built from a C# .NET project for which I am responsible for maintaining/developing.

Answer (score 0):

My reason for asking was flawed; the root cause was actually [Microsoft.Dexterity.Support.FilterEvents.dll](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/developingfordynamicsgp/archive/2010/09/10/revisited-modal-windows-issues-in-gp-10-0-fixed-in-10-0-sp5.aspx) being installed when it shouldn't have been, not any artifacts directly left behind from the GP 10 installation.

The only artifact I've actually seen left behind (with, admittedly, minimal testing) is the *%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Dynamics\GP* folder. Perhaps the list in the [GP 10 manual uninstall instructions](http://dynamicsgpblogster.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-dynamics-gp.html) is comprehensive and only items in it are candidates for being left behind after a proper uninstall.